# Need to add a condition between two fields in a view

Tags: entities

I am a Drupal 7 novice. I have two fields of two different contents in a view. The first field is a boolean and the second is text (configured to an external link). Now, I want to make a condition like "If the first field is `Yes`, then the second field should be hidden."

Comment: There is also http://drupal.org/project/field-conditional-state

Comment: Yes I need it only for a view. I think I have not explained my problem clearly. Here it is. Field 1 is Delivery (yes/no);
Field 2 is Deliver (Global Text with link to open a form);
both fileds are displaying in a row of a table view. Requirement: If Delivery / yes then Deliver / yes (without link);
If Delivery / no then Deliver / yes (with the link which will open the form to edit); I hope it is clear now.

Comment: So, isn't my answer useful ?

Answer (score 7):

This can be accomplished through the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).  However, if you are a PHP novice, you would probably be better off using the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.  Although this is still in dev (no official release) for Drupal 7, it does work.  (If you have security-related requirements, you should use Form API instead though.)

Basically, the module provides you with a UI for adding conditions to fields.  The example you give is the same given on the module's page, so this is one solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can try Form API for a Form but how to use it in a view as per my requirement ? views_ifempty module might be helpful and trying to solve the problem with this also. Your suggestion please.

Comment: http://knackforge.com/blog/selvam/drupal-7-fapi-using-form-states-conditional-field-display

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is about views, whether displaying a field or not, not in the node form.

Then my advice, without using views PhP, would be to use **no-result behaviour** in your view :

1. Add your text field, and hide it
2. Add your boolean field, and use **rewrite the output**, and in it set your text field with the given token
3. Use **no result behaviour** on that field, and put either nothing, either what you want to be displayed when your boolean field is set to no.

Hint : for your *no result behaviour* to be triggered when your boolean field is set to no, you have to ensure the key of the "no" is either "0" or empty. To be sure, check the option **Count the number 0 as empty** .